# jQuery reversing the order of child elements

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to reverse the order of child elements with jQuery.

For example, if I start with:

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

I want to end up with this:

```
<ul>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>A</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: are you doing a sorting type of thing? If not you can do something like this http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: I'm not really sorting here, but I have a separate task that will involve sorting. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Edit: [Anurag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5347903/610585) is better than mine.

```
ul = $('#my-ul'); // your parent ul element
ul.children().each(function(i,li){ul.prepend(li)})
```

If you call .prepend() on an object containing more than one element, the element being appended will be cloned for the additional target elements after the first, so be sure you're only selecting a single element.

Comment: i dont think that would get rid of the listed elements though. So you would get a reverse list and the original list. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Matt - a DOM element can only exist at one place, so in this case it is moved around, not copied.

Comment: in fact, you can copy and paste the code and try it on this page, and see the menu bar reverse itself.

Comment: One more clarification:  if you call .prepend() on an object containing more than one element, the element being appended will be cloned for the additional target elements after the first.  So `$('.many-elements').prepend($('#unique-element')` is going to create copies of the element with id #unique-element. The example above will do this, on a page with multiple `ul` elements, but this won't: 
`uls = $('ul'); // all UL elements
uls.each(function(i,ul){
 $(ul).children().each(function(i,li){$(ul).prepend(li)})
})`

Answer (score 143):

```
var list = $('ul');
var listItems = list.children('li');
list.append(listItems.get().reverse());
```

Comment: I never noticed this answer before now, but I'll agree that it's better than my answer.  Mine just illustrates an interesting property of append/prepend.

Comment: Short and sweet. One question: What's the difference between `listItems.reverse();` and `listItems.get().reverse()`? I don't understand why the first one doesn't work, isn't ListItems an array of `<li>` elements?

Comment: listItems is an instance of the jQuery object which wraps an array of DOM elements. It isn't a regular array why is why we call get() on it to get back a plain array which we know can be reversed.

Comment: @tfmontague - Do you have performance benchmarks to prove that?

Comment: @Anurag - I've retracted my earlier statement. Benchmarks show that list.prepend() and list.append() have faster performance than list.html() - http://jsperf.com/reversehtmlvsappend

Comment: @tfmontague - yeah though it's only marginally faster. I wouldn't care about the differences..

Comment: Performance is the least of the issues with `.html()` - you should _never_ use `.html` or anything else that serialises the DOM and then deserialises it again just to move elements.  That's what node objects are for!

Comment: I disagree with that statement. If using `.html()` *somehow* turned out to be noticeably faster than reordering node elements and your application demands performance and this element reorder is a bottleneck, then by all means please go ahead and use `html()`. The reason I would prefer *not* to use `html()` is because of incorrectness. `html()` will recreate all those elements from scratch and any state that is not serialized such as event handlers will get lost. So it won't simply be a reorder operation anymore but a slightly more destructive operation with other side-effects.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
  var x = $('li');
  $('ul').empty().append(x.reverse());
});
```

Comment: You're creating an unused array with `[]`. Wouldn't it be better to use `Array.prototype.reverse` instead of `[].reverse`?

Comment: The `.empty` is redundant - each element object only exists once and will be automatically removed from its original position in the DOM as its put back into its new position.

Answer (score 3):

All the answer given before me are best but you can try this also

```js
$('#btnrev').click(function(){

$('ul').html($('ul').find('li').get().reverse());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>

<button id="btnrev">
click
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

oneliner:

```
$('ul').append($('ul>').detach().get().reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

### No Jquery Solution

```
Element.prototype.reverse = function(){
    var c = [].slice.call(this.children).reverse();
    while (this.firstChild) { this.removeChild(this.firstChild); };
    c.forEach(function( child ){ this.appendChild(child) }.bind(this))
}
```

And use like :

```
document.querySelector('ul').reverse(); // children are now reversed
```