# Multiple ul reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and I have a page with multiple unordered lists ul.
I need to reverse order each ul, I saw this answer [jQuery reversing the order of child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347839/jquery-reversing-the-order-of-child-elements)
but it messes all items with all lists.
I tried to change the code to fit my needs but it doesn't do what I want, I can access each li of each ul but I don't know how to reverse the order of the li items.

My code:

```
$(function() {
  ul = $('ul'); // your parent element
  ul.each(function(i,ul){
     $(this).children().each(function (i,li) {
        alert(i);/*i got to do something here*/
     });
  })  
});
```

Comment: Can you please show your current HTML and how you expect it to end up ....

Comment: Please, put your code on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for when you have multiple `ul`'s: http://jsfiddle.net/dG373/4/

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

-

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    var ul = $(this);
    ul.children().each(function(i, li){
        ul.prepend(li)
    });
});
```

Comment: Mark it as an answer by clicking the `✓` sign below the score =)

Answer (score 1):

You can move elements around in the DOM quite easily, by inserting them either before or after other elements. When you get a set of elements in a jQuery instance (e.g., using `$(...)`), you get a static set of the elements that matched, in document order. So reversing them at that point is just a matter of looping through the matched set and moving them:

```
var list = $("selector_for_the_list");
var items = list.children();
var index;
for (index = items.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
    list.append(items[index]);
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/apuzib)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

1.) select the items you wish to reverse the order of (e.g. `$("div.myitems")`)

2.) call `$.makeArray` on the items to turn into a *true* array.

3.) call the javascript `.reverse()` method to invert the array.

I've never done this so I'm not sure if it will work, but it might give you some ideas to build on!