# Display inline block elements from bottom up, with trailing elements on top

Tags: html, responsive-design, css

I have a `<ul>` of `display:inline-block` list items - they display as expected, wrapping around like text in a paragraph when they reach the end of the line. [See example](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/JkZsD/) in which there are 6 elements, 4 on the first line and 2 on the second.

I'd like to have the trailing elements on the top rather than the bottom. To build on the previous example, if there's 6 elements, I want 2 to be on top and 4 on bottom.

[Here's an updated version of the elements](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/JkZsD/1/) with what I'm looking for, however this solution uses multiple `<ul>` elements which is not an option because the number of elements will frequently change and I cannot hard code it each time, especially with mobile device considerations.

I'd prefer a non-JavaScript solution if at all possible. As I hinted, it should be a responsive solution that fits at all page widths (no problem if it's not always 2 on top, 6 on bottom, just generally more on bottom and fewer on top).

My biggest issue is at some screen sizes my elements are making an upside-down pyramid shape due to the sizes & placements, and I think a right-side-up pyramid would be preferable.

### For the visual learners

**What is**

[image]

**What should be**
[image]

### Relevant example code

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

Comment: You are literally going against the flow, that is, the way the CSS text flow model works.  CSS formats block level elements from top to bottom, left to right.  You are trying to do the opposite.  You will need a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not reversing the order of the html elements? Anyway you can reverse the order using Js as shown here:
[jQuery reversing the order of child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347839/jquery-reversing-the-order-of-child-elements)

Or you can try using flexbox though the support for it is lacking: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: I'm not so much concerned with the order elements appear so much as the arrangement of them. Thanks though!

Comment: Well, the arrangement is directly connected to the order elements appear, that is who the basic elements flow works.

Answer (score 1):

As my predecessors said you are going against the natural order of things here ;) but...

Depending on how the content is generated (CMS etc.) you could just count the elements and give the second one a class with which you could add a right margin so that the row is occupied.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this through CSS. By setting the position to relative, and adding the top attribute set to 100%, the elements will render from the bottom up.

Comment: You're on the right track - they do go bottom->up. But the sill go left-to-right. If you have 4 boxes, the last one wraps to the bottom left - I'd like it on the top left. http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/9sNBy/3/

Answer (score 1):

should you try:

```css
li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <br>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" /></li>
</ul>
```