# Change order of several lists at once

Tags: jquery, html, list

How can I change the order of both lists, while preventing to mix them up. I know how to do it with one list, but get stuck when I got several..

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfSTf/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="switch_order">Switch</a>
```

jQuery

```
$('body').on('click', '.switch_order', function(e){
  var list = $('ul');
  var listItems = list.children('li');
  list.append(listItems.get().reverse());
});
```

Comment: What exactly did you mean by change the order..??

Comment: That A and B switch, so B becomes the first li tag and A second, and in the second list same story with C and D

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347839/jquery-reversing-the-order-of-child-elements

Comment: The answer of the above question mixed up my ul's, so that was not the answer I was looking for, so it's a slightly different question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('body').on('click', '.switch_order', function(e){
    $('ul li').each(function(i,li){
        $(this).parent().prepend(li);
    })
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pfSTf/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('click', '.switch_order', function(e){
 $('ul').each(function(){
  var listItems = $(this).children('li');
  $(this).append(listItems.get().reverse());
 });
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfSTf/1/)

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something with each() but didn't know how to place it, this really helps!

Answer (score 0):

[This is one way](http://jsfiddle.net/pfSTf/4/)

```
All I did here was give an id to each <ul> and targeted them seperately
```

Comment: That's an option indeed, but I got a list where people can add some ul's and li's, so I try to not work with an id