# jQuery - Button to arrange elements by id in descending order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collection of divs with id of 0, 1, 2, 3, n. They are generated in php in ascending order. I want to make a button to re-arrange them so they display in descending order using jquery. I have absolutely no clue how to do this. Can anyone refer me to an article or something?

Code:

```
<span>
    <div id="0">...</div>
    <div id="1">...</div>
    <div id="2">...</div>
    <div id="3">...</div>
    <div id="4">...</div>
    ...
</span>
```

I want a button to make it:

```
<span>
....
    <div id="4">...</div>
    <div id="3">...</div>
    <div id="2">...</div>
    <div id="1">...</div>
    <div id="0">...</div>
</span>
```

Comment: And for your specific instance of the problem: [jQuery reversing the order of child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5347839/218196)

Comment: Those lis didn't have ids; therefor, the code to switch the order is different.

Comment: And yet the solution you accepted doesn't take the IDs of the `div` elements in account. So I wonder why it matters that the `li` elements don't have IDs. Of course there are multiple ways to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$('span div').each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore('span div:first');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BS4g3/

Comment: I works but I seem to trigger it with .click.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BS4g3/5/ here it is with a button

Answer (score 2):

Very simple.

Suppose that you have this current HTML:

```
<span>
    <div id="0">1</div>
    <div id="1">2</div>
    <div id="2">3</div>
    <div id="3">4</div>
    <div id="4">5</div>
</span>
```

Using a simple jQuery reverse will result in what you need:

```
$($("div").slice(1).get().reverse())
   .insertBefore("div:first");
```

Result:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/66QDc/

Edit:

I updated the fiddle a button to do the task:

http://jsfiddle.net/66QDc/1/

Comment: You ROCK man! Helped me a lot!