# How to create reversed unordered lists?

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I'm trying to get an unordered list to show its items in a reversed order. In other words, getting this:

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

To show:

- Three
- Two
- One

I tried jQuery with this answer: [jQuery reversing the order of child elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347839/jquery-reversing-the-order-of-child-elements)

However, it didn't work for me for some reason. (I put it in a .html file, and also I tried using `<script src="script.js"></script>`)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var list = $('ul');
var listItems = list.children('li');
list.append(listItems.get().reverse());

</script>

<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Additionally, that answer was from 4 years ago, so I'm wondering if there's now a better solution?

Comment: The code you posted works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/b5tf9c2r/) but you have to call it *after* the elements are rendered to the page.

Comment: Thank you, what a silly mistake on my part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script should be executed after the DOM (Document Object Model) is fully loaded.
Try replacing your script by

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var list = $('ul');
    var listItems = list.children('li');
    list.append(listItems.get().reverse()); 
});
```

You can read more here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ for more information.

Comment: Or simply move the code to the end of the page before the closing body tag.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It is however a good practice to call the script explicitly after document is ready. Also, this encloses the variables declaration within a function, thus preventing the global declaration.

Comment: In general yes, a good practice. But not a requirement for this basic example.

Comment: You can also use the small code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v00gr3gt/2/), working without jquery.