# How can I change the order of list items when I press a button with JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm an absolute JS beginner. I would appreciate your help for the following: I have the following HTML code. How can I change the order of li-s in a list when I press a button with JS? i.e.: Item1 should become Item2 and so on. I think it's possible to do this with "for(){}", I just don't know exactly how..

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li> 
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Have a try, come back when and if you get stuck on something

Comment: You don't specify the logic of order changing. Item 1 will become Item 2, when I press the button again, what will happen next and why? If you're absolute beginner, look at this: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery reversing the order of child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347839/jquery-reversing-the-order-of-child-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to start with picking the list we're actually planning to modify:

```
var listToModify = document.querySelector("ul");
```

Next, we need to get an iterator through the list items to shuffle around:

```
var listItemsToShuffle = listToModify.querySelectorAll("li");
```

Then we want to loop through our items and move them. I'm going to assume that reordering the list results will result in "Item4" ending up on the top.

```
for (var i = 0; i < listItemsToShuffle.length - 1; i++) {
    listToModify.appendChild(listItemsToShuffle[i]);
}
```

It seems like we're duplicating the list items but we're not. Same element/node cannot be duplicated (exist in two places), so the first one will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this would help you

```
var __ListItem = document.getElementById("listItemId");
function __shuffleList() {
    var __nodes = __ListItem .children, i = 0;
    __nodes = Array.prototype.sort.call(__nodes );
    while(i < __nodes .length) {
       __ListItem .appendChild(__nodes [i]);
       ++i;
    }
}
__shuffleList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
$('#btnrev').click(function(){

$('ul').html($('ul').find('li').get().reverse());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>

<button id="btnrev">
click
</button>
```

Comment: jQuery is not tagged on the question.