# How can I move a list item to the top on click?

Tags: javascript, html

If I click on a specific list item then it will goes to up in the list.
For example if i click on Price list it show above of the color list.

```js
function setOnTop() {
  var listItems = document.querySelector("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    listItems[$i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      //Move on top
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Color</li>
  <li>Size</li>
  <li>Price</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What happens if you click on "color"?

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762496/how-can-i-change-the-order-of-lis-in-a-list-when-i-press-a-button-with-js-wi

Comment: @Nikolay that question and way is different and its is the different from that, you can check again. its not by click on button.

Comment: JS _is_ JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul");
const li = ul.querySelectorAll("li");

function setTop() {
  ul.prepend(this);
}
li.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", setTop);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Color</li>
  <li>Size</li>
  <li>Price</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when you prepend the li why doesn't it add to the list of li(s) instead of moving the li from one place to another?